# Replacing dmref tags with XInclude tags correctly

Tags: xml, pdf-generation, xinclude

Fellow Forum Members,
I need help in replacing `<dmref>` tags with `<xinclude>` tags within a XML file known as a Publication Module (PM). My PM lists 125 XML files and I want to feed this PM file to my Arbortext XML Editor as a PM file it recognizes so that it can publish a single PDF file from all of the 125 XML files listed in the PM file. From what I understand the Xinclude function is suppose to make a single XML file out of all 125 XML files that Arbortext will not reject.

My problem is I can't find any coding examples of how the Xinclude function overwrites the dmref tag within the type of XML code that resides in a PM file. Below is an example of how to code Xinclude I found online:

```
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <title>The Wit and Wisdom of George W. Bush</title>
  <xi:include href="malapropisms.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="mispronunciations.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="madeupwords.xml"/>
</book>`
```

And below is an example of the dmref code residing inside my PM file. The `<dmCode>` points to an external data module (which really is an XML file that contains remove procedures). In short, I have had no success in getting the PDF to print out error free when I replace the dmref tag with the Xinclude code shown above. My hope is someone below can take a look at the code below and share what is the correct way to add the Xinclude funtion to it:

```
`<dmRef>
<dmRefIdent>
<dmCode assyCode="00" disassyCode="00" disassyCodeVariant="00"
infoCode="520" infoCodeVariant="A" itemLocationCode="O"
modelIdentCode="BIKE" subSubSystemCode="1" subSystemCode="0"
systemCode="A03" systemDiffCode="DE"/>
<issueInfo inWork="00" issueNumber="001"/></dmRefIdent>
<dmRefAddressItems>
<dmTitle>
<techName>Seat</techName>
<infoName>Removal</infoName>
</dmTitle>
<issueDate day="07" month="11" year="2013"/></dmRefAddressItems>
</dmRef>`
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated in the successful development of what I am calling a PM Wrapper file.  Thanks in advance.